# How to do a relative import when using Pycharm "Run in python console"?

Tags: python, pycharm, console

I am using `Pycharm` and its `Run in python console` feature.  It works well except when the source file is intended to be run as a module (`-m` option).

For example if a `python` source file includes:

```
from . import utils
```

Then when selecting a snippet -  via `Run in python console` - that includes/requires that import we get:

```
importError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

Is there any way to run this code in `Pycharm console` ?

Comment: Typical format:  "from <module> import <class> as <nickName>"

Comment: See python docs on imports:  https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: @RandyB. The `from . import utils` works using `python3 -m mymodule` from the cmd line: my question is about how to use it from within Pycharm | python console

Comment: @napuzba I do realize that - but then is there  a workaround in pycharm console?

Comment: @StephenBoesch, I see - added an answer how to update the starting script of python console of pycharm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit and adjust the starting script to your needs.

---

Go to **Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Console > Python Console**. You should find the following starting script:

```
import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS])
```

Now, You can adjust the script to your needs so it will not raise the errors related to relative imports.

Comment: oh Hold on - I already had those ! I think the problem is that the current working dir is in the child directory, whereas we need parent directory. Is there a way to update the path to inclue the parent something like `sys.path.extend([f'{WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS}/..'])`

Answer (score 1):

So as [napuzba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6582873/napuzba) stated in the accepted answer, you can add to the script.

If the location you wish to add is always relative to the `venv` location, which is accessible via an environment variable `VIRTUAL_ENV`, you can do something like adding the
following to the above accepted answer:

```
import os
import pathlib
sys.path.append( str(pathlib.Path(os.environ["VIRTUAL_ENV"], '..', 'imaging_lib' )))
```

I was in hunt for a solution, didn't find where PyCharm provided a way to get the root project dir in a simple manner. I had found that the `VIRTUAL_ENV` was available, which is just under the project root directory in my case.

So simply ascending up a level provided the project root, then adding a relative directory below the project root, in this example case, the directory `imaging_lib`. Using `pathlib` provided a clean, simple way to create the path, appropriate for the os file path format.

This provided a solution for myself.

Comment: Nice solution , happy to double your reputation score ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would try running the code from the CLI to see if you get a similar error.  If it works from the CLI then it maybe your console configuration.  If it doesn't work there either, then it can be one of two things:

1. pathing issue
2. module isn't coded properly

If the module is correctly made, and in you current path, you should be able to just import it:

```
import utils
```

If this isn't working then maybe you didn't setup your module properly.  For more info, see python docs on modules: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

If your custom module isn't in your current path, you may have to update the system path so that it can find your module.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\Users\\myUserName\\myDir') ## Add specific directory (windows 10)
sys.path.appen('/home/myUserName/myDir') ## Add specific directory (Unix/Linux example)
sys.path.append('..') ## Add parent directory

## Now that the system path has been updated, you can load your module
import myModuleName
from myModuleName import myClassName
```

One last tying to try is changing into the directory where the code resides and then run the python command from there.  Sometimes it is a pathing issue.  If this approach works, then write a bash/sh wrapper script which changes into the directory first then runs code.

To better understand which path your python code is running from, try running the code:

```
import os
print('cwd: %s' % os.getcwd())
```

Output:

```
cwd: C:\Users\rbala\code\test
```

Comment: I do realize the above - and for example know to adjust the `Run Configurations` appropriately  - but then is there a workaround in pycharm console?